# Grails error: No such property: it for class:

Tags: grails

Below is my code.
Here I am getting an error which is 'No such property: it for class: emp.EmployeeController'.
I think I am doing something wrong here.
Any advice??

```
def list ={

    def id=params.id
    def results

    String employee="SELECT empName, empDate, empNo from employee where empId='id'"     
    String referrer="SELECT  empName, empDate, empNo from referer where empId='id'"


    def employeeInstanceList = new ArrayList<Employee>()
    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    def joining=null
    joining = sql.rows( "select joining from employee_dates")


    if (joining!=null)      
    results = sql.eachRow(employee)
    employeeInstanceList=getCalculatedEmployeeData(results)
    /*{

        def employee = new Employee()
        employee.setempName it.empName
        employee.setEmpNo it.empNo
        employee.setEmpDate it.EmpDate
        employeeInstanceList.add employee
    }*/

    else

    results = sql.rows (currentDaySql)
    employeeInstanceList=getCalculatedEmployeeData(results)
    /*{
        def employee = new Employee()
        employee.setempName it.empName
        employee.setEmpNo it.empNo
        employee.setEmpDate it.EmpDate
        employeeInstanceList.add employee       }*/ 

    }


    [employeeInstanceList: [employeeInstanceList: employeeInstanceTotal: Employee.count()]
}


def getCalculatedImpactData(def results){
        def employee = new Employee()
        employee.setempName it.empName
        employee.setEmpNo it.empNo
        employee.setEmpDate it.EmpDate
        employeeInstanceList.add employee       }*/
    return [employeeInstanceList: employeeInstanceList]
}
```

Thanks,
Meghana

Answer (score 2):

There is so much wrong with that code, I don't know where to start...

But to avoid getting more down votes I have tried :)

I tried to copy your code into an IDE and try and work out what you are trying to achieve but couldn't.

This is as close as I could get it:

```
 def list = {
        def id = parmas.id
        def results

        String employee = "SELECT empName, empDate, empNo from employe"

        def employeeInstanceList 
        Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        def joining = sql.rows("select joining from employee_dates")

        if (joining != null) {
            results = sql.eachRow(employee)
            employeeInstanceList = getCalculatedEmployeeData(results)
        }
        else {
            results = sql.rows(currentDaySql)
            employeeInstanceList = getCalculatedEmployeeData(results)
        }

        [employeeInstanceList: employeeInstanceList, employeeInstanceTotal: Employee.count()]
    }


    def getCalculatedImpactData(def results) {
        def employeeInstanceList = new ArrayList<Employee>()
        results.each { it ->
            def employee = new Employee()
            employee.empName = it.empName
            employee.empNo = it.empNo
            employee.empDate = it.EmpDate
            employeeInstanceList.add(employee)
        }
        return employeeInstanceList
    }
```

but it is still referring to a variable currentDaySql which doesn't exist and I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the 'joining' result.

You really need to read up on Groovy basics.

Answer (score 2):

i would second leebutts answer... but just a pointer, the usage of the *it* keyword is usually confined to closures... so instead of doing this in java:

```
List l = [];
for (Iterator i = l.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  ...do something adressing List l at position i...
}
```

you could do this in groovy / grails:

```
list.each { it ->
  ...do something with each object in the list (it)...
}
```

but you should really read up on groovy closures at http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures

Answer (score 0):

The block of code where the error occurs is probably:

```
def getCalculatedImpactData(def results){
    def employee = new Employee()
    employee.setempName it.empName
    employee.setEmpNo it.empNo
    employee.setEmpDate it.EmpDate
    employeeInstanceList.add employee
    return [employeeInstanceList: employeeInstanceList]
}
```

`it` is not defined anywhere (hint: the compilation error told you this). Like Sebastian said, `it` is typically used in closures; what you've defined here is a function. Presumably you wanted to use `results` (or something) instead of `it` here.

I'm assuming that some of the things in your code (e.g. comment opening/closing) weren't in there and were added between when you saw the error and when you posted the code. Otherwise you'd get other errors.